# Class component is declared but its value is never read

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnNsO.png)
hi everyone. i am getting an error like this. How to can ı solve ?

Comment: Hi, please refrain from post your code as an image, post is as a formatted text instead. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15366635). You can check out the [Stack Overflow editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to guide you on formatting your codes. Goodluck :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must rename "followup" to "Followup"

Component name must be Uppercase